# How can I alias multiple (but not all) imports in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I want to import some (but not all) functions from a module and group them under a common "namespace".

I know I could do

```
import * as Foo from 'Foo'
```

but then AFAIK the whole module is loaded.
I want

```
import {a, b} from 'Foo'
```

and then call it like

```
Foo.a()
```

Is that possible?

Comment: When you say _"group them under a common namespace"_ do you mean a _"globally accessible namespace"_ - if yes, is this within a node.js or browser context ?  Or, is the _"namespace"_ only local, i.e.  calling `Foo.a()`, and/or `Foo.b()` will be performed from the same module as the `import` statement ?

Comment: From the same as the import statement.

Comment: `import * as Foo` and `import {a, b}` both load all of `Foo`, there is no difference to how many things are loaded as long as your bundler can look at the code and see what properties on `Foo` are accessed.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Wait, you mean I could always import everything? UI thought we need to specify in the imports to reduce bundle size.

Comment: As long as your bundler can tell what properties are being accessed on `Foo`, it is no different from listing the names directly in the `import`. So as long as you're not doing `var name = "a"; Foo[name]();` or something it doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I am not so sure about it. For example, it may be that the bundler just trys to retrieve the specified properties (`a` and `b`) without checking whether others exist or not. Also, importing just function names may be different from importing the functions themselves.

Comment: A later `const Foo = {a, b};` is the best you can do, since a syntax like `import {a, b} as Foo from 'Foo'` is (sadly) invalid.